# How Do I debug a fault exception

Tags: c#, soap

How do I  debug a faultexception

I am getting this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <env:Body>
 <env:Fault>
  <faultcode>env:Client</faultcode>
  <faultstring>Rejected by policy. (from client)</faultstring>
  </env:Fault>
 </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

The documentation provided says it could be because of 
The Missing,Invalid User ID or Credentials fault is encountered when the User ID or Password not specified or incorrect within the data-stream

I am giving the correct password, userid. 
Could it be because of a invalid usernametoken or x509 certificate.

Comment: Do you have access to the service code?  What type of service is this (WCF)?

Comment: Its an external service and I have no control over it. They gave me the wsdl, xsd's and a sample soap request. By the soap request I think it is written in Java. The username token has nonce and created by for which I did some custom classes.

Comment: Download the WcfTestClient and use it to tinker with the parameters and possibly obtain further debug info to Google.  If that doesn't work then I recommend you contact the owner of the code for support.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx

Comment: wcfTestClient.. When I try to add a service reference, it won't do that. This is the url given for the service in their documentation.  https://service100.emedny.org:9047/MHService. I went to their wsdl and create a proxy class using svcutil to be able to use their methods

Comment: Try https://service100.emedny.org:9047/MHService?wsdl

Comment: Yes I tried that. It adds a reference when I use the wsdl. Although it gives me a bunch of error about Custom tool error, global type has been defined in both xsd' and they are different and that kinda stuff. So went to advanced and unchecked 'Resuse Types in referenced assemblies'. Doesn't seem to work. So had to use svcutil. Not sure if I am not understanding this correctly or if its a fault on their end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by [configuring tracing on the server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx).  Verbose traces might give you a clue as to what's happening.

Comment: Please take a look at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574863/wcf-client-trace-svclogfile-fault-exception. This is what my trace file has to say.

Comment: Not that I fixed it but atleast the log says something abt missing security header

Answer (score 0):

How to debug it? Download [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) and look for differences in the messages sent in the client that works and the client that doesn't work.

Comment: @user575219 Misread. compare it to your sample soap requests, which presumably work.