# Security processor was unable to find a security header in the message.

Tags: wcf, soap

In my many trials to debug this

```
    Exception: `System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: Security processor was unable to find a security header in the message. 
This might be because the message is an unsecured fault or because there is a
     binding mismatch between the communicating parties.   This can occur if the service is configured for security and the client is not using security`
```

[How Do I debug a fault exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16550355/how-do-i-debug-a-fault-exception)

I am not sure if this is why my response says 'Rejected by policy from client' 
This is just a guess if it could be because of the additional junk which in  soap header . 
My code generated a soap header which looks like this

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1" u:Id="_3"/>
    <a:MessageID u:Id="_4">urn:uuid:9659b138-7fc0-4bb6-8c0a-bae00336ba78</a:MessageID>
    <a:ReplyTo u:Id="_5">
      <a:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
    <VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">
      uIDPo/RnkzjA3fBPjgXUnYt8J3IAAAAAoMwUVXqfw0yigCfFtptf4RNq4s3l6eJLuuLNNdxRoH4ACQAA
    </VsDebuggerCausalityData>
    <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1" u:Id="_6">https://service100.emedny.org:9047/MHService</a:To>
    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="uuid-8d1465b7-c0fd-4137-9361-d0a818286435-53" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3">
        <!--Removed-->
      </o:BinarySecurityToken>
      <o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="uuid-8d1465b7-c0fd-4137-9361-d0a818286435-52" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3">
        <!--Removed-->
      </o:BinarySecurityToken>
    </o:Security>
  </s:Header>
  ...
</s:Envelope>
```

This is the sample soap request for vendor

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mhs="http://org/emedny/mhs/" xmlns:urn="urn:hl7-org:v3">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    <wsse:BinarySecurityToken ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="SecurityToken-e00c8062-83d2-4f04-88fc-996218e7bb3d">MIICeDCC....(eMedNY signed user MLS cert).......</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
    <wsse:BinarySecurityToken ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="SecurityToken-c0cc2cd4-cb77-4fa5-abfa-bd485afd1685">MIIDFj.....( eMedNY MLS web-service end-point public cert)........</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
```

This is the additional stuff my client code generates

```
<a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1" u:Id="_3"/>
<a:MessageID u:Id="_4">urn:uuid:9659b138-7fc0-4bb6-8c0a-bae00336ba78</a:MessageID>
<a:ReplyTo u:Id="_5">
  <a:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:Address>
</a:ReplyTo>
<VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">
  uIDPo/RnkzjA3fBPjgXUnYt8J3IAAAAAoMwUVXqfw0yigCfFtptf4RNq4s3l6eJLuuLNNdxRoH4ACQAA
</VsDebuggerCausalityData>
<a:To s:mustUnderstand="1" u:Id="_6">https://service100.emedny.org:9047/MHService</a:To>
```

How would I remove this?

Internet recommends using Imessageinspector and custombehviour

```
    public class CustomMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
    {
        #region IClientMessageInspector Members

        public void AfterReceiveReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
        }

        public object BeforeSendRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel)
        {
            request.Headers.RemoveAll("Action", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing");
            request.Headers.RemoveAll("MessageID", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing");
            request.Headers.RemoveAll("ReplyTo", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing");
            request.Headers.RemoveAll("To", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing");

            return null;
        }
        #endregion
    }

    public class CustomBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
    {
        <--removed some more classes-->      
        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientRuntime behavior)
            {
                //Add the inspector
                behavior.MessageInspectors.Add(new CustomMessageInspector());
            }
     }
```

then finally in the call to the proxyclient

```
MHSClient proxy = new MHSClient(GetCustomBinding(), 
                                new EndpointAddress(new Uri("https://service100.emedny.org:9047/MHService"),
                                EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("DPMedsHistory"));

proxy.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new CustomBehavior());


private static Custombinding GetCustomBinding()
{

            var b = new CustomBinding();
            var sec = (AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement)SecurityBindingElement.CreateMutualCertificateBindingElement(MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10);
            sec.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.Signed.Add(new X509SecurityTokenParameters());
            sec.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.Signed.Add(new UserNameSecurityTokenParameters());
            sec.MessageSecurityVersion =
                MessageSecurityVersion.
                    WSSecurity10WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10;
            sec.IncludeTimestamp = false;

            sec.MessageProtectionOrder = System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageProtectionOrder.EncryptBeforeSign;
            TextMessageEncodingBindingElement textEncBE = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, Encoding.UTF8);
            HttpsTransportBindingElement httpsBE = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();


            CustomBinding myBinding = new CustomBinding();
            myBinding.Elements.Add(sec);
            myBinding.Elements.Add(textEncBE);
            myBinding.Elements.Add(httpsBE);

            return myBinding;
}
```

THis doesn't work or rather gives me an error:

> No signature message parts were specified for messages with the '' action.

Comment: What does GetCustomBinding() do?

Comment: Analyze the WCF serviced log file for more details. Also are you using secure conversations to the service in the custom binding. Post the binding info in service and client after analyzing the log files.